# What is the counter used for doors?

Tags: counters

This is from deceze, but what is the counter used for doors.  Is it 枚(mai)　or something else?

Comment: Looks like 枚　or 本　is ok, but I never heard of that myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to this page](http://www.benricho.org/kazu/ta.html), it's 一枚、一本 (いちまい, いっぽん). Found it under 戸 (と).

Comment: wow, great link btw.  Should probably get that added to the FAQ

Comment: I would use 一枚.  In fact, I did not know that a door can be counted as 一本.

Comment: That site seems to fall back on 一本 for a few things which aren't cylindrical (e.g. 大仏). Maybe they were talking about revolving doors?

Comment: @nevan: (1) I think that the website states 大仏 is counted as 一体.  But I started to be a little worried about the correctness of the website, seeing that it shows the pronunciation of 大仏 as たいぶつ while the correct pronunciation is だいぶつ.  (2) I would not count revolving doors as 一本 either, but it is hard to say how to count them because I have never encountered the situation where I have to count them.

Comment: Ah, I misread it. I have no idea how accurate that site is, I only found it today. They also say that 夜着 is やぎ. They have a lot of counters though. (The revolving doors was just a joke).

Comment: Note that 戸 itself is actually a counter, but is mostly (only?) used to count number of houses.  The same way "three doors down" actually means "3 houses down" or "3 rooms down" in English.

Comment: @istrasci: You are right that 戸 is also used as a counter word, but not to count doors.  Besides, 戸 as a counter word is pronounced こ, not と.